# Fill up and down cells in multiple columns based on a condition

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following columns and values:

```
Begin Time  Other values    First Name  Last Name   other info
5041*       value1                                  info1
5041*       value2          firstname1  lastname1   info2
13089       value3                                  info3
16130       value4                                  info4
19739       value5                                  info5
26300       value6                                  info6
26391*      value7          firstname2  lastname2   info7
27878       value8                                  info8
27878       value9                                  info9
28234       value10                                 info10
28738       value11                                 info11
29854       value12                                 info12
63110       value13                                 info13
63189*      value14         firstname3  lastname3   info14
64335       value15                                 info15
65423       value16                                 info16
72089*      value17                                 info17
72089*      value18         firstname4  lastname4   info18
73495       value19                                 info19
73495       value20                                 info20
74330       value21                                 info21
74877       value22                                 info22
76710       value23                                 info23
82599*      value24                                 info24
82599*      value25          firstname5 lastname5   info25
86712*      value26                                 info26
98712*      value27          firstname6 lastname6   info27
98725       value28                                 info28
100605      value29                                 info29
100605      value30                                 info30
100954      value31                                 info31
```

I expect this:

```
Begin Time  Other values    First Name  Last Name   other info
5041        value1          firstname1  lastname1   info1
5041        value2          firstname1  lastname1   info2
13089       value3          firstname1  lastname1   info3
16130       value4          firstname1  lastname1   info4
19739       value5          firstname1  lastname1   info5
26300       value6          firstname1  lastname1   info6
26391       value7          firstname2  lastname2   info7
27878       value8          firstname2  lastname2   info8
27878       value9          firstname2  lastname2   info9
28234       value10         firstname2  lastname2   info10
28738       value11         firstname2  lastname2   info11
29854       value12         firstname2  lastname2   info12
63110       value13         firstname2  lastname2   info13
63189       value14         firstname3  lastname3   info14
64335       value15         firstname3  lastname3   info15
65423       value16         firstname3  lastname3   info16
72089       value17         firstname4  lastname4   info17
72089       value18         firstname4  lastname4   info18
73495       value19         firstname4  lastname4   info19
73495       value20         firstname4  lastname4   info20
74330       value21         firstname4  lastname4   info21
74877       value22         firstname4  lastname4   info22
76710       value23         firstname4  lastname4   info23
82599       value24         firstname5  lastname5   info24
82599       value25         firstname5  lastname5   info25
86712       value26         firstname6  lastname6   info26
98712       value27         firstname6  lastname6   info27
98725       value28         firstname6  lastname6   info28
100605      value29         firstname6  lastname6   info29
100605      value30         firstname6  lastname6   info30
100954      value31         firstname6  lastname6   info31
```

I am using the following code thanks to [@Jeeped's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29883967/4835480)

```
Sub FillColBlanksSpecial()

Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim col As Long
Dim lRows As Long
Dim lLimit As Long

Dim lCount As Long
On Error Resume Next

lRows = 2
lLimit = 1000

Set wks = ActiveSheet
 For Each wks In Worksheets
        If Right(wks.Name, 2) = "-A" Or Right(wks.Name, 2) = "-B" Then
            With wks
                With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
                    With .Columns("C:D")
                        If CBool(Application.CountBlank(.Cells)) Then
                            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=r[-1]c"
                        End If
                    End With
                    'un comment the next line if you want the formulas to revert to values only
                    .Cells = .Cells.Value
                End With
            End With
        End If
    Next wks
End Sub
```

The goal is to fill down the values in the **columns C & D** until the next value in sheets with **-A** and **-B** in suffixed in the sheetnames.

### But

as you see in the example data, I want this filling down take into account the codes in the first column.
For example: in **A2** & **A3** the code is **5041**, so I want to **fill up** the **row 2** with the values in **C3** and **D3** (i.e. *firstname1* & *lastname1*), and then fill down the same values until the next occurrence of values in **columns C & D** (i.e. *firstname2* & *lastname2*) or sometimes one row before the next occurrence because that one row shares the same code in column A with the one after itself. And example for this latter one is filling down *firstname3* & *lastname3* until one row before the occurrence of *firstname4* & *lastname4* because the row shares the same code in **column A** with the following *firstname4* & *lastname4* which is going to be **filled up** by *firstname4* & *lastname4* in its turn.

*How to modify this vba code to accommodate this condition?*

[Here is the excel worksheet with a longer example data. The workbook contains two sheets: *what I have* & *what I expect*.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B73smSNUQ01-RUNZUFNxM0xqelU/view?usp=sharing)

**P.S.** the asterisk mark besides the codes in first column are solely for the purpose of the visual accessibility; otherwise they don't appear in the original data sheet.

Comment: @pnuts if the begin time is the same as the begin time of the next firstname/lastname, then it should stop there, because the row which shares the same begin time with the following firstname/lastname will be filled up with that follorwing first/lastname. Begin times are UNIQUE for each first/lastname, one row upper or below may share the same begin time with first/lastname.

Comment: @pnuts every first/lastname has a unique `begin time`: meaning **no other** row in which there is a first/lastname value share the same `begin time`. But sometimes, those empty rows may share the same `begin time` with its adjacent row which contains first/lastname.

Comment: @pnuts column **other values** is simply other unique values per row; nothing to do with this operation.

Comment: @pnuts yes you are right, I had a mistake in the question text. Column A is the `begin time` code, column B is the `other values`, and column C is the *firstname* and column D is the *lastname*. Sorry.

Comment: @pnuts I have hundreds of sheets in one workbook, and each sheet has hundreds of rows like this, I want to do this only in sheets ending in **-A** or **-B**. That is why I need a vba code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to have to fill in a formula that is a little more complicated. Additionally, since this formula looks both up and down before settling on a default, the formulas *must* be resolved to their returned values before proceeding to the next blank cell in order that the value can be used in future lookups without causing a circular reference.

```
Sub FillColBlanksSpecial2()

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim blnk As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim col As Long
    Dim lRows As Long
    Dim lLimit As Long

    Dim lCount As Long
    On Error Resume Next

    lRows = 2
    lLimit = 1000

    Set wks = ActiveSheet
    For Each wks In Worksheets
        If Right(wks.Name, 2) = "-A" Or Right(wks.Name, 2) = "-B" Then
            With wks
                With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
                    With .Columns("C:D")
                        If CBool(Application.CountBlank(.Cells)) Then
                            For Each blnk In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
                                blnk.FormulaR1C1 = "=if(countifs(r1c1:r[-1]c1, rc1, r1c:r[-1]c, ""<>""), index(r1c:r[-1]c, match(rc1, r1c1:r[-1]c1, 0)), if(countifs(r[1]c1:r9999c1, rc1, r[1]c:r9999c, ""<>""), index(r[1]c:r9999c, match(rc1, r[1]c1:r9999c1, 0)), r[-1]c))"
                                blnk.Value = blnk.Value
                            Next blnk
                        End If
                    End With
                End With
            End With
        End If
    Next wks
End Sub
```

The new formula in xlR1C1 and xlA1 (as seen from C2) is,

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(R1C1:R[-1]C1, RC1, R1C:R[-1]C, "<>"), INDEX(R1C:R[-1]C, MATCH(RC1, R1C1:R[-1]C1, 0)), IF(COUNTIFS(R[1]C1:R9999C1, RC1, R[1]C:R9999C, "<>"), INDEX(R[1]C:R9999C, MATCH(RC1, R[1]C1:R9999C1, 0)), R[-1]C))
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$1:$A1, $A2, C$1:C1, "<>"), INDEX(C$1:C1, MATCH($A2, $A$1:$A1, 0)), IF(COUNTIFS($A3:$A$9999, $A2, C3:C$9999, "<>"), INDEX(C3:C$9999, MATCH($A2, $A3:$A$9999, 0)), C1))
```

- The formula first looks to see if there is a value in column A above it with a non-blank *First Name* and if there is one, it accepts it and moves on.
- If a value above it was not found, it then looks for a match below it where *First Name* is not blank. If found, it accepts it and moves on.
- If neither was found, it accepts the value directly above it as the default.

If you follow that logic, you can see that the formulas *have* to be reverted to values right away or a subsequent formula could find it as a formula and create a circular reference. This is a little slower as it loops through the `xlCellTypeBlanks` instead of pushing formulas and values in blocks but it is thorough.

Comment: first thanks for helping me to sort this out. Second, I tried to use your VBA code, but it didn't trigger anything, no errors and nothing. My excel's delimiter is **;** instead of *,** so I replaced them in the formula in the VBA code, but still nothing. Where should I use the formula you put down in your answer? is it already integrated in the VBA? if so, it is not the same, if not, then where should I put it? I am a bit confused about the steps that I should follow. Please help, thanks.

Comment: @Mpondomise - My apologies. I left my test worksheet name in the conditions and unless yours was identically named every worksheet would have been skipped over. I've reset the code back to the original test for -A and -B.

Comment: I think your answer is doing what I wanted to do. However I would like to know what I would like to know why you have repeated your formula twice in your explanations? are they the same?

Comment: @Mpondomise - They are both identical as looked at from the perspective of the C2 cell. An xlR1C1 style formula does not change at all depending if you are putting it into C2 or D32. However, the relative cell references *will* change in an xlA1 style. This is why an xlR1C1 style was used in the code. However, some people (not you!) have a hard time reading an xlR1C1 style so I included the equivalent xlA1 style so other readers could see what I was trying to do.

Comment: you are so nice. But I am still one of those who have problem reading the xlR1C1 style. I am a newbie. You saved me a lot of time with this answer. Thanks. i wish I had more points to give to this answer.

Comment: I have encountered a problem and I need to modify the code to accommodate for this extra rule: sometimes there are several rows that need to be ***filled up*** in columns **C:D**. Earlier I mentioned that only one row could be empty and needs to take its values from the row below because it shares the same value in column **A** with the row below. But now I realized that there could be several rows that have their **C:D** empty and need to fill them up with the row which is several rows below and which shares the same cell value in the **A**. How to modify this code? Thanks so much.

Comment: Do I need to put this as a new question? please let me know @jeeped 
thanks

Comment: @Mpondomise - I think that would be best in order that the new situation receives focused attention. I had a look earlier and TBH, my head was swimming a bit but I had planned to review it again later. If you bring the new situation to a new question, all of the older debris can be left behind.