# Fill up and down cells in multiple columns based on values in another column

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following columns and values:

```
Begin Time  Other values    First Name  Last Name   other info
5041*       value1                                  info1
5041*       value2          firstname1  lastname1   info2
13089       value3                                  info3
16130       value4                                  info4
26391*      value5                                  info5
26391*      value6                                  info6
26391*      value7          firstname2  lastname2   info7
27878       value8                                  info8
27878       value9                                  info9
28234       value10                                 info10
63189*      value11                                 info11
63189*      value12                                 info12
63189*      value13                                 info13
63189*      value14         firstname3  lastname3   info14
64335       value15                                 info15
65423       value16                                 info16
72089*      value17                                 info17
72089*      value18         firstname4  lastname4   info18
73495       value19                                 info19
73495       value20                                 info20
74330       value21                                 info21
74877       value22                                 info22
76710       value23                                 info23
82599*      value24                                 info24
82599*      value25          firstname5 lastname5   info25
98712*      value26                                 info26
98712*      value27          firstname6 lastname6   info27
98725       value28                                 info28
100605      value29                                 info29
100605      value30                                 info30
100954      value31                                 info31
```

I expect this:

```
Begin Time  Other values    First Name  Last Name   other info
5041        value1          firstname1  lastname1   info1
5041        value2          firstname1  lastname1   info2
13089       value3          firstname1  lastname1   info3
16130       value4          firstname1  lastname1   info4
26391       value5          firstname2  lastname2   info5
26391       value6          firstname2  lastname2   info6
26391       value7          firstname2  lastname2   info7
27878       value8          firstname2  lastname2   info8
27878       value9          firstname2  lastname2   info9
28234       value10         firstname2  lastname2   info10
63189       value11         firstname3  lastname3   info11
63189       value12         firstname3  lastname3   info12
63189       value13         firstname3  lastname3   info13
63189       value14         firstname3  lastname3   info14
64335       value15         firstname3  lastname3   info15
65423       value16         firstname3  lastname3   info16
72089       value17         firstname4  lastname4   info17
72089       value18         firstname4  lastname4   info18
73495       value19         firstname4  lastname4   info19
73495       value20         firstname4  lastname4   info20
74330       value21         firstname4  lastname4   info21
74877       value22         firstname4  lastname4   info22
76710       value23         firstname4  lastname4   info23
82599       value24         firstname5  lastname5   info24
82599       value25         firstname5  lastname5   info25
98712       value26         firstname6  lastname6   info26
98712       value27         firstname6  lastname6   info27
98725       value28         firstname6  lastname6   info28
100605      value29         firstname6  lastname6   info29
100605      value30         firstname6  lastname6   info30
100954      value31         firstname6  lastname6   info31
```

I am using the following code thanks to [@Jeeped's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29917115/fill-up-and-down-cells-in-multiple-columns-based-on-a-condition/29918926#29918926)

```
Sub FillColBlanksSpecial2()

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim blnk As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim col As Long
    Dim lRows As Long
    Dim lLimit As Long

    Dim lCount As Long
    On Error Resume Next

    lRows = 2
    lLimit = 1000

    Set wks = ActiveSheet
    For Each wks In Worksheets
        If Right(wks.Name, 2) = "-A" Or Right(wks.Name, 2) = "-B" Then
            With wks
                With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
                    With .Columns("C:D")
                        If CBool(Application.CountBlank(.Cells)) Then
                            For Each blnk In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
                                blnk.FormulaR1C1 = "=if(countifs(r1c1:r[-1]c1, rc1, r1c:r[-1]c, ""<>""), index(r1c:r[-1]c, match(rc1, r1c1:r[-1]c1, 0)), if(countifs(r[1]c1:r9999c1, rc1, r[1]c:r9999c, ""<>""), index(r[1]c:r9999c, match(rc1, r[1]c1:r9999c1, 0)), r[-1]c))"
                                blnk.Value = blnk.Value
                            Next blnk
                        End If
                    End With
                End With
            End With
        End If
    Next wks
End Sub
```

with the formula in xlR1C1 style and its xlA1 equivalent:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(R1C1:R[-1]C1, RC1, R1C:R[-1]C, "<>"), INDEX(R1C:R[-1]C, MATCH(RC1, R1C1:R[-1]C1, 0)), IF(COUNTIFS(R[1]C1:R9999C1, RC1, R[1]C:R9999C, "<>"), INDEX(R[1]C:R9999C, MATCH(RC1, R[1]C1:R9999C1, 0)), R[-1]C))
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$1:$A1, $A2, C$1:C1, "<>"), INDEX(C$1:C1, MATCH($A2, $A$1:$A1, 0)), IF(COUNTIFS($A3:$A$9999, $A2, C3:C$9999, "<>"), INDEX(C3:C$9999, MATCH($A2, $A3:$A$9999, 0)), C1))
```

The goal is to **fill up and down** the columns **C:D** with the existing values based on the conditions:

1. Take the values in **C:D** and fill down until the next non-empty cell in the same columns.(these non-empty cells contain unique values, firstname1, firstname2, etc)

2. Take the values in **C:D** and fill **up** if the empty row(s) above share the same value in **Column A** with the row which is below and whose values we are coping up.

@Jeeped's answer is working correctly:
*it takes the values from columns **C:D** and fills down the empty rows until the next row that contains new values; it also fills up one empty row if the that empty row shares the same value in column **A** with the row below that contains the to-be-copied values.*

but it only **fills up one row.** My example data (link below) shows that there might be ***more than one empty row*** above the rows that contain values in column **C:D** that need to be filled up.

**How to modify this vba code to accommodate this condition?**

[Here is the excel worksheet with a longer example data. The workbook contains two sheets: *what I have* & *what I expect*.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B73smSNUQ01-NnZ6VlVvQ1JXMjg/view?usp=sharing)

**P.S.** the asterisk mark besides the codes in first column are solely for the purpose of the visual accessibility to identify the empty rows that share the same value in column **A** with the row below that has values in columns **C:D**; otherwise they don't appear in the original data sheet.

By **empty row**, I mean those rows which don't have values in columns **C:D**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've complicated the formula a bit more to achieve the vertical lookup to more than a single column. The single line that needs modification is in the center of all the nested code.

```
blnk.FormulaR1C1 = "=if(countifs(r1c1:r[-1]c1, rc1, r1c:r[-1]c, ""<>""), index(r1c:r[-1]c, match(rc1, r1c1:r[-1]c1, 0)), if(countifs(r[1]c1:r9999c1, rc1, r[1]c:r9999c, ""<>""), index(r[1]c:r9999c, min(index(row(r:r9998)-row(r[-1])+((r[1]c1:r9999c1<>rc1)+not(len(r[1]c:r9999c)))*1e+99, , ))), r[-1]c))"
```

That translates to an xlA1 style formula like the following (as seen from C2).

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$1:$A1, $A2, C$1:C1, "<>"), INDEX(C$1:C1, MATCH($A2, $A$1:$A1, 0)), IF(COUNTIFS($A3:$A$9999, $A2, C3:C$9999, "<>"), INDEX(C3:C$9999, MIN(INDEX(ROW(2:$9998)-ROW(1:1)+(($A3:$A$9999<>$A2)+NOT(LEN(C3:C$9999)))*1E+99, , ))), C1))
```

Note that the coded formula requires doubling up the quotes within the quoted string.

Comment: You are the [hero of SO excel-vba tag!](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/excel-vba/topusers). Thanks

Comment: Thanks for that; I wasn't aware of that stat. I'm rapidly approaching a milestone here at SO and glad you were a part of it.