# Fill blank cells above and below based on a condition in another column

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following columns and values:

```
User ID     Input B    Input C    Input D     ...   Input ZZ

id_value1              c_value1                     
id_value1                                          
id_value1                         d_value1          zz_value1
id_value1   b_value1                                
id_value2   b_value2                                
id_value2                                           zz_value2
id_value2              c_value2   d_value2          
id_value2                                           
id_value2                                           
id_value3              c_value3                     
id_value3   b_value3              d_value3          zz_value3
id_value4                                           
id_value4   b_value4                                        
id_value4                                           zz_value4
id_value4              c_value4   d_value4
id_value4
```

And I want to achieve the following:

```
User ID     Input B    Input C    Input D     ...   Input ZZ

id_value1   b_value1   c_value1   d_value1          zz_value1
id_value1   b_value1   c_value1   d_value1          zz_value1
id_value1   b_value1   c_value1   d_value1          zz_value1
id_value1   b_value1   c_value1   d_value1          zz_value1
id_value1   b_value1   c_value1   d_value1          zz_value1
id_value2   b_value2   c_value2   d_value2          zz_value2
id_value2   b_value2   c_value2   d_value2          zz_value2
id_value2   b_value2   c_value2   d_value2          zz_value2
id_value2   b_value2   c_value2   d_value2          zz_value2
id_value2   b_value2   c_value2   d_value2          zz_value2
id_value3   b_value3   c_value3   d_value3          zz_value3
id_value3   b_value3   c_value3   d_value3          zz_value3
id_value4   b_value4   c_value4   d_value4          zz_value4
id_value4   b_value4   c_value4   d_value4          zz_value4
id_value4   b_value4   c_value4   d_value4          zz_value4
id_value4   b_value4   c_value4   d_value4          zz_value4
id_value4   b_value4   c_value4   d_value4          zz_value4
```

The goal is this:

Within each set of rows with the same value in column A (these rows are contiguous), use the single instances of values present in columns B:ZZ to fill any blank cells in those columns both up and down.

Put another way, for any value in columns B:ZZ, fill that value both up and down until the value in column A changes.

Put yet another way, for any blank cell, find a nonblank cell above or below with a matching value in rc1 and take that cell's value.

My pseudocode approach would be as follows:

```
for each blankcell:
    find nonblank above
    if nonblank.rc1 == blankcell.rc1:
       blankcell == nonblank
    else find nonblank below
    if nonblank.rc1 == blankcell.rc1:
       blankcell == nonblank
    else do nothing
```

This seems relatively straightforward, but I don't know how to implement it in VBA.

I've been trying to tinker with [@Jeeped's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30009534) for solving a similar problem, but haven't been successful.

```
Private Sub FillColBlanksSpecial2()

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim blnk As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim col As Long
    Dim lRows As Long
    Dim lLimit As Long

    Dim lCount As Long
    On Error Resume Next

    lRows = 2
    lLimit = 1000

    Set wks = ActiveSheet
        With wks
            With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
                With .Columns("B:ZZ")
                    If CBool(Application.CountBlank(.Cells)) Then
                        For Each blnk In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
                            blnk.FormulaR1C1 = "=if(countifs(r1c1:r[-1]c1, rc1, r1c:r[-1]c, ""<>""), index(r1c:r[-1]c, match(rc1, r1c1:r[-1]c2, 0)), if(countifs(r[1]c1:r9999c1, rc1, r[1]c:r9999c, ""<>""), index(r[1]c:r9999c, min(index(row(r:r9998)-row(r[-1])+((r[1]c1:r9999c1<>rc1)+not(len(r[1]c:r9999c)))*1e+99, , ))), r[-1]c))"

                            blnk.Value = blnk.Value
                        Next blnk
                    End If
                End With
            End With
        End With
End Sub
```

As I understand it, this code fills upwards based on the value in column A, but downwards until it finds any new value (not dependent on the column A condition). I'm also hesitant to employ the code as I don't have an understanding of the logic of the min() function.

Any insight in to how to implement my pseudocode approach or any alternative approach would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How does column A get populated?

Comment: The number of rows in column A per unique 'User ID' is determined by the number of trials each user completed in a task.  Each user completed a variable number of trials.  (For purposes of clarity I have omitted a set of columns which reflect unique trial data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps try something like the below?

```
Sub FillValues()

    Dim tempRange As Range, tempArray As Variant, rowStart As Long, rowEnd As Long, lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, tempValue As Variant

    ' The assumption is that we are starting in row 2, and go as far down as there are cells in Column A
    ' Also that we are using Column A as a reference.
    ' So we start by getting this range and assigning it to our variable.
    lastRow = Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    Set tempRange = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("A2:A" & lastRow).EntireRow)

    ' We are going to assume that we are not concerned about pasting formats etc.
    '(If we are concerned with that, we would need to change our code)
    'Set the tempArray to be this range that we acquired above.
    tempArray = tempRange.Value

    rowStart = 1
    While rowStart <= lastRow

        rowEnd = rowStart

        ' First get the rows we are going to be looking at
        ' Keep iterating rowEnd until we find a new value, or we reach the end
        While tempArray(rowEnd, 1) = tempArray(rowStart, 1) And rowEnd < lastRow
            rowEnd = rowEnd + 1
        Wend
        ' If we did reach a new value, go back one to get the real row range.
        If Not tempArray(rowEnd, 1) = tempArray(rowStart, 1) Then rowEnd = rowEnd - 1

        ' Now that we have a range, we loop over the row range and column range.

        ' For each column
        For j = 2 To lastCol

            ' Cycle through the rows to find an acceptable value
            tempValue = ""
            For i = rowStart To rowEnd
                If Not Len(tempArray(i, j)) = 0 Then tempValue = tempArray(i, j): Exit For
            Next i

            ' If we found a value, populate the whole section accordingly
            If Not Len(tempValue) = 0 Then
                For i = rowStart To rowEnd
                    tempArray(i, j) = tempValue
                Next i
            End If

        Next j

        ' After we did this for each column, we now need to iterate to the next section
        rowStart = rowEnd + 1

    Wend

    ' Finally we put the new data back into the sheet
    tempRange = tempArray

    ' And clear the variables
    Set tempRange = Nothing: Set tempArray = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks for the elegant, well-commented solution.  (The only adjustment that I had to make was to change A2 to A1 in the tempRange definition, otherwise an out-of-index error was thrown when rowEnd = lastRow).

Answer (score 0):

This simple formula fill with a subsequent reversion from formula to value should suffice.

```
Sub blah()
    With Worksheets("Sheet7")
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            If CBool(Application.CountBlank(.Cells)) Then
                With .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
                    .FormulaR1C1 = _
                      "=LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(RC1, ""id_"", SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1, COLUMN(), 4, 1) & CHAR(95), 1, """")))"
                End With
            End If
            .Cells = .Cells.Value
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

I hope that your actual data follows the pattern exhibited by your sample data.

[image: zz_value4]

Comment: Apologies, in my effort to be simple and generalizable, I believe I have been confusing.  The values that I've described (id_value1, b_value2, \*_value\*, etc.) refer to variables (all integers, except id_value), not string literals. Also in my specific case, the actual columns in question range from I:KX. Again, I was trying to be generalizable, which may have been ultimately unhelpful.  Your input is very much appreciated though, I'm glad for help from the stackoverflow wizard of VBA!