# Auto fill multiple sections of varying length in VBA in one Column

Tags: excel, vba, autofill

I need some assistance in developing a macro to autofill text in sections of varying length in Column A. I am new to VBA and I've tried record macro but it defines the section to a specific range which could vary every time I run the macro. The first cell to auto fill down always begins in cell A3. There are relevant values in column B (they are dates).

I cannot find anything like this scenario in the web.

Comment: What defines the size of the area to be filled?

Comment: The next cell in Column A with a value. I found this code with works for just the first section. Can it be modified to repeat varying sections?Range("A3").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
Selection.FillDown

Comment: No, not sure how that looks in code. Do you know of a way to get the code in the prior comment to repeat?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29883803/fill-down-blank-cells-in-multiple-columns-in-specific-sheets

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
Sub FillDown()
Range("B3", Range("B3").End(xlDown)).Offset(, -1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
End Sub
```

Or in one line:

```
Range("B3", Range("B3").End(xlDown)).Offset(, -1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
```